# Ошибка при компиляции проекта в intellij idea scala: Error:scalac: No 'scala-library*.jar' in Scala compiler classpath in Scala SDK SBT: org.scala-

Tags: intellij-idea, scala, sbt

Доброго времени суток, суть проблемы вот в чём:

У меня  **intellij idea 2017.2.4 community edition + scala plugin 2017.2.7**.

Создаю новый scala проект, выбираю систему сборки **sbt 1.0.2** и версию **scala 2.11.11**.

[image: Окно создания проекта] 
Далее создаю scala объект `Run`

```
object Run extends App {
   println("Hello World!")
}
```

Запускаю нажав `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `F10` и получаю вот такое сообщение об ошибке:

```
Error:scalac: No 'scala-library*.jar' in Scala compiler classpath in Scala SDK SBT: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.11:jar
```

После этого ничего не меняя открываю `Idea SBT Shell` и запускаю проект командой `run`:

```
[IJ]sbt:scala-test-project> run
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\CODE\scala-test-project\target\scala-2.11\classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Packaging C:\CODE\scala-test-project\target\scala-2.11\scala-test-project_2.11-0.1.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Running Run
[debug] Waiting for threads to exit or System.exit to be called.
[debug]   Classpath:
[debug]         C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\sbt_e96ae4bc\job-1\target\b8aa1b93\scala-test-project_2.11-0.1.jar
[debug]         C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\sbt_e96ae4bc\target\e283d2b7\scala-library-2.11.11.jar
[debug] Waiting for thread run-main-0 to terminate.
Hello World!
[debug]         Thread run-main-0 exited.
[debug] Interrupting remaining threads (should be all daemons).
[debug] Sandboxed run complete..
[debug] Exited with code 0
[success] Total time: 5 s, completed 30.09.2017 11:44:50
```

Ошибки нет.
Подскажите пожалуйста, кто встречался с проблемой? Как решается? Это баг или просто что-то делаю не так?

Если использовать версию `scala 2.12.3` такой проблемы нет.

Также если изменить версию `sbt` на 0.13.15 проблема тоже пропадает.

В файле `build.sbt`:

```
name := "scala-test-project"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это баг. Скорей всего баг принадлежит IDEA. Чтоб поправить нужно:

1. Открыть `Project Structure` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)
2. Выбрать в разделе `Project Settings` подраздел `Libraries`.
3. Добавить в список `Compiler classpath:`

   - /home/***enver***/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.11.jar
   - /home/***enver***/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.11.jar

(Разумеется тебе надо поменять пути на свои, например заменить **enver** - на имя своего пользователя в системе)

Comment: Спасибо заработало :-) Будем надеяться скоро баг поправят.